# How to use case statement multiple times on same column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like for the amount to be displayed, if zero was not shown, this query is received for me only separately

How do I add this request to my request

```
case when [Summa]=0 then null else round(a.Summa,2) end as Summa
```

This is the request I need

```
SELECT
    [a].[id],
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), [a].[Date], 104) AS [Data],
    [j].[Login],
    [b].[Name] AS [NameAgency],
    [c].[Name] AS [NamePosition],
    [d].[Name] AS [NameOperatonsType],
    [e].[Name] AS [NamePartnerType],
    [f].[Name] AS [NameType],
    [g].[Name] AS [NamePartners],
    [h].[name] AS [NameBank],
    [i].[name] AS [NameCurrency],
    CASE       
        WHEN [d].[ID] = 2 THEN
            '0'
        ELSE
            [a].[Summa]
    END AS [Prikhod],
    CASE
        WHEN [d].[ID] = 1 THEN
            '0'
        ELSE
            [a].[Summa]
    END AS [Raskhod],
    [a].[Comment]
FROM
    [Operations] AS [a] LEFT JOIN
    [Agency] AS [b] ON [a].[AgencyID] = [b].[ID] LEFT JOIN
    [Position] AS [c] ON [a].[PositionID] = [c].[ID] LEFT JOIN
    [OperatonsType] AS [d] ON [a].[OperType] = [d].[ID] LEFT JOIN
    [PartnerType] AS [e] ON [a].[ParentID] = [e].[ID] LEFT JOIN
    [NameType] AS [f] ON [a].[NameTypeID] = [f].[ID] LEFT JOIN
    [Partners] AS [g] ON [a].[PartnerID] = [g].[id] LEFT JOIN
    [Bank] AS [h] ON [a].[BankID] = [h].[id] LEFT JOIN
    [Currency] AS [i] ON [a].[CurrencyID] = [i].[id] LEFT JOIN
    [Users] AS [j] ON [a].[UserID] = [j].[ID]
WHERE
    [a].[Date] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
ORDER BY
    [a].[id] DESC;
```

[image]

I want to replace 0 with NULL for the columns Prikhod and Raskhod. Please let me know what changes need to be done.

Comment: you want to replace 0 with NULL for Prikhod and Raskhod column correct??

Comment: Yes, I want to replace 0 with NULL for the columns Prikhod and Raskhod

Comment: Your question is closed

Comment: question is Open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *,case when Prikhod = 0 then NULL ELSE Prikhod END ,case when Raskhod = 0 then NULL ELSE Raskhod END   from (
SELECT
    [a].[id],
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), [a].[Date], 104) AS [Data],
    [j].[Login],
    [b].[Name] AS [NameAgency],
    [c].[Name] AS [NamePosition],
    [d].[Name] AS [NameOperatonsType],
    [e].[Name] AS [NamePartnerType],
    [f].[Name] AS [NameType],
    [g].[Name] AS [NamePartners],
    [h].[name] AS [NameBank],
    [i].[name] AS [NameCurrency],
    CASE       
        WHEN [d].[ID] = 2 THEN
            '0'
        ELSE
            [a].[Summa]
    END AS [Prikhod],
    CASE
        WHEN [d].[ID] = 1 THEN
            '0'
        ELSE
            [a].[Summa]
    END AS [Raskhod],
    [a].[Comment]
FROM
    [Operations] AS [a] LEFT JOIN
    [Agency] AS [b] ON [a].[AgencyID] = [b].[ID] LEFT JOIN
    [Position] AS [c] ON [a].[PositionID] = [c].[ID] LEFT JOIN
    [OperatonsType] AS [d] ON [a].[OperType] = [d].[ID] LEFT JOIN
    [PartnerType] AS [e] ON [a].[ParentID] = [e].[ID] LEFT JOIN
    [NameType] AS [f] ON [a].[NameTypeID] = [f].[ID] LEFT JOIN
    [Partners] AS [g] ON [a].[PartnerID] = [g].[id] LEFT JOIN
    [Bank] AS [h] ON [a].[BankID] = [h].[id] LEFT JOIN
    [Currency] AS [i] ON [a].[CurrencyID] = [i].[id] LEFT JOIN
    [Users] AS [j] ON [a].[UserID] = [j].[ID]
WHERE
    [a].[Date] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    ) t
ORDER BY
    t.[id] DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in function for this: [NULLIF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). This functions returns `NULL`, whenever the first argument is the same as the second.

In your case you say: *Return NULL if my CASE evaluates to `0`*.

Try it out:

```
SELECT NULLIF(
        CASE WHEN [d].[ID] = 2 THEN '0'
        ELSE [a].[Summa] END, '0') AS [Prikhod],
       NULLIF(
        CASE WHEN [d].[ID] = 1 THEN '0'
        ELSE [a].[Summa] END, '0') AS [Raskhod]
FROM...
```

Hint: Depending on the datatype of `a.Summa` it might be a bad choice to state the zero values as string (`'0'`). The implicit conversion will hopefully return waht you expect, but it is better to stick to one data type explicitly.